# MySQL - If schema exists select from that schema

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to:

1. Check if a schema exists
2. If exists select some data

This is my idea:

```
SELECT * FROM my_schema.some_table
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='my_schema'
);
```

It throws following error:

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'my_schema.some_table' doesn't exist
```

I need it for the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT message FROM my_schema_1.some_table
UNION ALL
SELECT message FROM my_schema_2.some_table
UNION ALL
SELECT message FROM my_schema_3.some_table
)
AS result limit 1000;
```

...to avoid an error if a schema does not exist.

I guess you get the idea, but how to achieve it with MySQL?

Comment: Noway in single query.

Comment: I will update my question with a more complex query where I need to use it.

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve. What should be a result of this statement when there's no such table?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please look at it now. It contains the complex query I need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql - create dynamic union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923079/mysql-create-dynamic-union)

Comment: I'll check it out and give feedback.

Comment: @astentx Thanks for the link. It is a very good hint in what direction to go. I would need to modify it to fit my needs, but for now I do not have so much time to experiment. I will solve the problem for now on the server side. Quicker to implement, and easier to maintain for now. When I find time I will implement the solution using the link you provided me and post it here if I succeed.

Comment: As already mentioned above: not in a single query. The query planner already needs to know check whether the tables used in the query exist before the query gets executed, so any information you try to retrieve from the information schema is not available yet at that point.